# Using CSS Values in a D3 Transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, d3.js

I'd like to make d3 transition to a style defined in CSS. I can successfully transition to a style value which I explicitly apply in code. But, I'd like the target values of the animation to be defined in a style sheet.

Here's an example of a red div which transitions to a blue one:

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
        <style>            
            div {
                background: red
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Hello There</div>

        <script>
            d3.select('body div')
                .transition()
                .duration(5000)
                .style("background", "cornflowerblue");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's a my (incorrect) attempt at "storing" these values in CSS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
        <style>            
            div {
                background: red
            }

            div.myDiv {
                background: cornflowerblue
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Hello There</div>

        <script>
            d3.select('body div')
                .transition()
                .duration(5000)
                .attr("class", "myDiv");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The former animates the background from red to blue. The latter jumps from red to blue (no tweening is applied to background value defined in the CSS).

I think I understand why it doesn't work. Can I animate to a set of values in a CSS style in d3, and how would I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`selection.style`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-style) will return the browser generated style (from external CSS) if you don't pass a value to it. To get the background color for example:

```
var bg = d3.select('div').style('background-color');
```

You could append some hidden elements with the classes you need to fetch the colors from CSS if you don't want to hardcode them in your JS. Something like

```
var one = d3.select('body').append('div').class('my-first-color');
var two = d3.select('body').append('div').class('my-second-color');
```

Then `one` and `two` would have the styles you need. So.

```
var fake_div = d3.select('body').append('div').attr('class', 'some_class').style('display', 'none'),
    new_color = fake_div.style('background-color');

// We don't need this any more
fake_div.remove();
// Now we have an explicit value, effectively fetched from our CSS
d3.select('div').style('background-color', new_color);
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linssen/zasDK).

Comment: Thanks. That's useful to know, however it applies the style change immediately, it does not animate the change to the calculated style. Also, passing null to remove the style doesn't animate either.

Comment: I mean you append your fake divs then use their generated styles as an explicit value for your real one. See [this JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linssen/zasDK)