# Transitions styles back to CSS defaults

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm working on some `D3` visualizations and what I've found is that I'm having to define a lot of styles in my code - that really I'd prefer to have just in my `CSS`.

The reason for doing this is simply to support transitions. I've found that I can run a transition from a style applied in `CSS` to an inline one, but then I can't remove that style back to the original. Instead all of them need to be in-line. Like in the following example:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var c1 = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "red")
            .attr("r", 25)
            .attr("cx", 50)
            .attr("cy", 50);

var c2 = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 25)
            .attr("cx", 250)
            .attr("cy", 50)
            .style("fill", "red");

svg.selectAll("circle")
   .transition()
   .delay(2000)
   .duration(2000)
   .style("fill", "blue");

c1.transition()
  .delay(5000)
  .duration(2000)
  .style("fill", "");

c2.transition()
  .delay(5000)
  .duration(2000)
  .style("fill", "red");
```

```css
.red { 
   fill: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500">
</svg>
```

The circle on the left jumps straight back to red, while the one on the right transitions back.

What I'd like to do is transition the left circle back, without having to re-define the original colour I'm using from CSS in my Javascript code.

Does anyone know of an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like your `c1.transition()` might be missing the actual fill color to transition back to before it reverts to the original red? ( `.style("fill", "red");` )

Comment: @Evan - that is the point. I do *not* want to embed the colour from the CSS `red` into my Javascript....

Comment: how come you dont want to define the colour to transition back to ?

Comment: Is setting a local var to the current color before you start, then using that as the return value not an option?

Comment: @AJ_91 - because if I change the colour in my CSS (where I deem styling should live), I then also need to modify my Javascript to add the original colour in.

Comment: @DBS: That may be an option - someone actually posted that as an answer and deleted - but I believe currently is the most appropriate option. I guess what'd be nice is if the transition were to just `know` that I'm styling the fill and to check the CSS fill style first.

Comment: Use `getComputedStyle()` to get the current style of the element (AFTER CSS), transition to the new color, then revert back to your stored color.

Comment: can you not transition between css classes ?

Comment: @AJ_91 I don't believe that's possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213942/using-css-values-in-a-d3-transition : http://jsfiddle.net/linssen/zasDK/

Comment: So that you know you can create transitions for SVG elements in CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/14pv0kmh/. Don't know how much that helps you - just throwing it out there

Comment: I think @most platforms IE does not support CSS animations applied to SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So using Gilsha's answer I managed to figure out that you can actually grab the original CSS style later on so you don't need to save it. Seems even when the colour is blue, I can go back and grab the red colour:

```
c1.transition()
  .delay(5000)
  .duration(2000)
  .style("fill", function(d) { 
       var selection = d3.select(this);
       var currentStyle = selection.style("fill");
       var defaultStyle = selection.style("fill", null).style("fill");
       selection.style("fill", currentStyle");
       return defaultStyle;
 });
```

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var c1 = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "red")
            .attr("r", 25)
            .attr("cx", 50)
            .attr("cy", 50);

var c2 = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 25)
            .attr("cx", 250)
            .attr("cy", 50)
            .style("fill", "red");

svg.selectAll("circle")
   .transition()
   .delay(2000)
   .duration(2000)
   .style("fill", "blue");

c1.transition()
  .delay(5000)
  .duration(2000)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
       var selection = d3.select(this);
       var currentStyle = selection.style("fill");
       var defaultStyle = selection.style("fill", null).style("fill");
       selection.style("fill", currentStyle);
       return defaultStyle;
  });

c2.transition()
  .delay(5000)
  .duration(2000)
  .style("fill", "red");
```

```css
.red { 
   fill: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
var color = c1.style("fill");
```

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var c1 = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("class", "red")
            .attr("r", 25)
            .attr("cx", 50)
            .attr("cy", 50);

var c2 = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 25)
            .attr("cx", 250)
            .attr("cy", 50)
            .style("fill", "red");

//Get fill color from css
var color = c1.style("fill");

svg.selectAll("circle")
   .transition()
   .delay(2000)
   .duration(2000)
   .style("fill","blue");

c1.transition()
  .delay(5000)
  .duration(2000)
  .style("fill", color);

c2.transition()
  .delay(5000)
  .duration(2000)
  .style("fill", "red");
```

```css
.red { 
   fill: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500">
</svg>
```